# Allow jQuery function to be applied to multiple tags

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I use the following little jQuery code;

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#download-btn').click(function() {
            $("#download-btn").html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved" aria-hidden="true"></span> Downloaded');
            $("#download-btn").last().addClass("disabled");
        })
    });
</script>
```

and it works as it should - when I click a button with the ID `#download-button`, it adds a new class, and replaces some html/text. Now, this only seems to work for one button, the top one. It looks like this;

[image]

Both buttons are exactly the same,

```
<button id="download-btn" type="button" class="center btn btn-primary">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span> Download</button>
```

I want the jQuery to be applied to the clicked object only, but *any* clicked object that has the id `#download-btn`, not just the top one.
I could not seem to figure out how to do this without giving every download button a seperate, unique ID and repeat the jQuery function - I was hoping there was a better solution to this.

Comment: Don't use same id, use class istead

Answer (score 4):

There is two things you should do here

1. Use a class on all buttons you want to apply the same behaviour to - ID's should be unique
2. Use `$(this)` inside the handler so that the action(s) get applied to only the *clicked* button (you can also chain together those two actions)

html:

```
<button class="download-btn" type="button" class="center btn btn-primary">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" aria-hidden="true"></span> Download</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.download-btn').click(function() {
    $(this).html('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-saved" aria-hidden="true"></span> Downloaded')
           .addClass("disabled");
})
```

However, there is a further enhancement here too - you dont need to *completely replace the html* - instead you could just toggle the class inside the inner span.

```
$('.download-btn').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("disabled")
           .find("span.glyphicon").removeClass("glyphicon-save")
                        .addClass("glyphicon-saved");
})
```

The above needs some additional work to change the text of the button, i'll leave that to you if you decide to go this route (hint: put the text in another `span` element!)

Comment: Brilliant! Thank you. I am only left with one problem here, and that is removing the ´href´ from the ´a´ tag which isn't "in" the button, but around it (´<a><button>Download</button></a>´), is there a way to *only* target the a tag that interfears with the clicked object/button?

Comment: You have a link *around* the button. Ok weird, but anyhow - `$(this).parents('a')`

Comment: Ok, thanks, will try that. "Ok weird,", how would I do otherwise? If I make the button an ´a´ and center it, it turns to a "block" button/goes from the very left to the right of the website - I haven't found a way to "fix" this other than provoiding pixel sizes, which isn't optimal.

Comment: I only said weird because a `a` is a link and a `button` is an action. The two elements do similar things so combining them seemed a bit weird. What does the `a` do that the `button` couldnt?

Comment: Then why not just set the `location.href` inside the button click - thats what I mean - you're complicating things by having it wrapped with an `a`. You know when the button is disabled - you added a class for that - so just dont set the location when the button is disabled.

Comment: Well I want the button only to be click-able once, so when you click the button it downloads a file, making the button disabled and not click-able.

Comment: You can use the jQuery method [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to have the event handler fired only the first time, then disable the button from it and change the href of the anchor (if the button tag is a direct child of the anchor tag, `$(this).parent()` works too)

Answer (score 1):

This isn't good programming practice. Element-ID's should be unique within the entire document.

Comment: Give them the same class, or select the buttons with jQuery. `$("button']")`

Comment: But will this Apple the chance to every button with the class, or only the clicked one?

Comment: if you use `$(this)` within the handler only the clicked one, if you use a specific selector like `$("button") ` it will be applied on all button-tags.

Answer (score 0):

Give a different ID to every Button and if you want the same functionality to two button then give the same class name to the buttons and call that class name in javascript or jquery and if you want different functionality to every button than use particular ID and in one page all button have same functionality call by button tag in script.